# Mudar de pagina no mesmo ficheiro php

Tags: jquery

Boas pessoal

Sou novo no php e tenho aqui uma duvida

O meu desafio é criar um site (coisa simples), com 3 páginas uma homepage, contactos e uma pagina com os produtos.

Mas o problema é que tenho ter o conteudo das 3 paginas no mesmo ficheiro . Ou seja tenho que q mudar de pagina (da homepage -> contactos) no mesmo ficheiro php (index).

Como faço?

Comment: Olá João, bem vindo ao SoPT , já tem algum código feito ? Se sim, pode postar aqui para uma melhor ajuda no seu problema?

Comment: Index.php     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Site - Homepage</title>
</head>

<body background= "image.jpg">

<font align= center face= "Comic Sans MS" size=-1 Color= #000000>
  <h1>Bem vindo ao site</h1>
 
<font align= left face= "Comic Sans MS" size=-1 Color= #000000>
  <h2>Destaques:</h2>

  <p>bla bla em desconto</p>

Comment: João, pode postar o código da sua index.php ?

Comment: Você quer  redirecionar para outra página quando clica num botão por exemplo?

Comment: Depois tenho mais 2 ficheiros.php que são os que quero juntar´

Comment: Sim por exemplo, Fábio. Mas o conteudo dos outros ficheiros devem de estar todo no index.php

Comment: Então, você pode simplesmente juntar o conteúdo dos outros ficheiros PHP no mesmo código onde você tem a index ou pode optar por ir para outra página clicando num botão

Comment: sim ok fábio e depois como faço?

Comment: Eu quero juntar todos os ficheiros no index, mas mesmo assim quero conseguir navegar no site como se tivesse em ficheiros diferentes.

Comment: Chama-se parametro e devo de usar o href

Comment: Eu acho que é melhor por exemplo você ter a index, e depois por exemplo uma tab ou algum botão para navegar para outra página, penso que será mais prático e ergonómico

Comment: Sim era o mais fácil mas o exercicio é ter tudo junto no mesmo ficheiro e mesmo usar conseguir navegar como se estivesse os ficheiros separados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso com php não dá. Pode no entanto fazer com javascript. Ou seja, todos os conteudos numa só página, e cada link faz desaparecer uns conteudos e aparecer outros:

Para este exemplo vou usar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```js
$('[data-pagina]').on('click', function(){
  var pagina = $(this).data('pagina');
  $('.pagina').hide();
  $(pagina).show();
});
```

```css
.pagina {
  display:none;  
}
.pagina#homepage {
  display:block;  /* aparecer esta por default, no carregamento da página
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li data-pagina="#homepage">homepage</li>
    <li data-pagina="#contactos">contactos</li>
    <li data-pagina="#produtos">produtos</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  
<div class="pagina" id="contactos">
  <h2>conteudos dos contactos</h2>
</div>
<div class="pagina" id="homepage">
  <h2>conteudos dos homepage</h2>
</div>
<div class="pagina" id="produtos">
  <h2>conteudos dos produtos</h2>
</div>
```

Código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        ul {
            text-align: right;
        }
        li {
            list-style:none;
             display:inline-block;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }
        .pagina {
            display:none;  
         }
         .pagina#homepage {
            display:block;  /* aparecer esta por default, no carregamento da página*/
         }
    </style>
    <title>Tudo numa só página</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li data-pagina="#homepage">homepage</li>
            <li data-pagina="#contactos">contactos</li>
            <li data-pagina="#produtos">produtos</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="pagina" id="contactos">
       <h2>conteudos dos contactos</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pagina" id="homepage">
       <h2>conteudos dos homepage</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pagina" id="produtos">
       <h2>conteudos dos produtos</h2>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('[data-pagina]').on('click', function(){
             var pagina = $(this).data('pagina');
             $('.pagina').hide();
             $(pagina).show();
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41380/discussion-on-answer-by-miguel-mudar-de-pagina-no-mesmo-ficheiro-php)